# How to run a flow once, automatically when starting mule?

Tags: java, mule

I have a java class that creates a clean MongoDB database with seeded collections.  It automatically identifies if the database is missing and creates it.  I would like to run this when I start MuleEsb.  This way I don't need to remember to invoke it before I start mule.  I was hoping to put it inside a flow and run that flow once, automatically when mule starts up.

Is there a way to do this one-time operation when mule starts?

--- Update ---

As per the conversation below I added the following to my mule config and the flow is automatically triggered.

```
<quartz:connector name="Quartz" validateConnections="true"/>

<flow name="testService1">
    <quartz:inbound-endpoint name="runOnce" repeatCount="0" repeatInterval="1" jobName="job1" connector-ref="Quartz">
        <quartz:event-generator-job>
            <quartz:payload>foo</quartz:payload>
        </quartz:event-generator-job>
    </quartz:inbound-endpoint>

    <logger message="INBOUND HEADERS = #[headers:inbound:*]" level="WARN"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I created a JIRA a month ago to request such a feature: http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6877

For now, you can use a trick: [a Quartz inbound endpoint with an event generator job](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Quartz+Transport+Reference#QuartzTransportReference-EventGeneratorJob) `repeatCount = 0` that will trigger your flow only once at startup.

Alternatively, you can listen to context events and invoke a flow when a specific event is triggered. The following shows a listener that invokes a startup and a shutdown flow:

```
package com.acme;

import org.mule.DefaultMuleEvent;
import org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage;
import org.mule.MessageExchangePattern;
import org.mule.api.MuleException;
import org.mule.api.MuleRuntimeException;
import org.mule.api.context.notification.MuleContextNotificationListener;
import org.mule.config.i18n.MessageFactory;
import org.mule.construct.Flow;
import org.mule.context.notification.MuleContextNotification;

public class FlowInvokingContextListener implements MuleContextNotificationListener<MuleContextNotification>
{
    private Flow startingFlow;
    private Flow stoppingFlow;

    public void onNotification(final MuleContextNotification notification)
    {
        if (notification.getAction() == MuleContextNotification.CONTEXT_STARTED)
        {
            sendNotificationToFlow(notification, startingFlow);
        }
        else if (notification.getAction() == MuleContextNotification.CONTEXT_STOPPING)
        {
            sendNotificationToFlow(notification, stoppingFlow);
        }
    }

    private void sendNotificationToFlow(final MuleContextNotification notification, final Flow flow)
    {
        try
        {
            final DefaultMuleEvent event = new DefaultMuleEvent(new DefaultMuleMessage(notification,
                notification.getMuleContext()), MessageExchangePattern.REQUEST_RESPONSE, startingFlow);
            flow.process(event);
        }
        catch (final MuleException me)
        {
            throw new MuleRuntimeException(MessageFactory.createStaticMessage("Failed to invoke: "
                                                                              + startingFlow), me);
        }
    }

    public void setStartingFlow(final Flow startingFlow)
    {
        this.startingFlow = startingFlow;
    }

    public void setStoppingFlow(final Flow stoppingFlow)
    {
        this.stoppingFlow = stoppingFlow;
    }
}
```

Configured with:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean name="flowInvokingContextListener"
        class="com.acme.FlowInvokingContextListener"
        p:startingFlow-ref="startFlow" p:stoppingFlow-ref="stopFlow" />
</spring:beans>

<notifications>
    <notification event="CONTEXT" />
    <notification-listener ref="flowInvokingContextListener" />
</notifications>
```

Comment: Nice answer!  Thank-you.  If I create a quartz inbound-endpoint, don't I also need to specify an outbound-endpoint?

Comment: No you don't, a single quartz inbound-endpoint in your flow will do it.

Comment: Since I'm using v3.2.1, the DefaultMuleMessage() constructor does not have a FlowConstruct option.  Plus I think the quartz solution is a little cleaner since it appears I can put the quartz:inbound-endpoint inside the flow I want to automatically run.  I'm not familiar with running a flow through quartz though.  Are there any examples of this?

Comment: Sure, look at the example there http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Quartz+Transport+Reference#QuartzTransportReference-EventGeneratorJob

Comment: Very helpful David.  Thank-you.  I updated the question above with the quartz example I am running.  It successfully triggers at start-up, though it runs twice instead of once.

Comment: A repeatCount of zero is what's needed.  Not one.  I'll update the question.  Thank-you again for your help!

Comment: Perfect, I fixed my answer. Gotta start thinking of upgrading BTW... Mule 3.2.1 is antiquated :)

Comment: what is p:startingFlow-ref - I don't see that namespace defined anywhere and all google searches I have done find this post and clones thereof. Would be great to know what p: is

Comment: This is the standard p namespace from Spring.

Comment: Not sure if I understand, what's the startFlow and stopFlow should look like? Cause console screams, that it's not recognizible.

Cannot resolve reference to bean 'startFlow' while setting bean property 'startingFlow'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'startFlow' is defined

Comment: @DawidWiniarz They both should be private flows.

Comment: Yes, I've checked it already. Is there any chance to start it in general, to listen to all flows?

Comment: Cause, my mian goal is to inform me, when for example someone will undeploy my mule app. So, there is a listener which will tell me, when the 'undeploy' event occurs.

Comment: @DawidWiniarz Mule notification framework will definitely raise events that you can listen to to be notified of an app going down.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a custom agent that does it: 
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Agents