# Notifications on Mule Server events

Tags: mule

I went through the Mule Notifications. But still not clear on configuring following:

1. I would like to send a email when Mule Server start or stop events.
2. I would like to send a email when any of mule applications deployed/undeployed.

Comment: Did you read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17459948/387927 ?

Comment: Thanks David. Is there anyway i can get mule service deploy/undeploy events through a listener.

Comment: By "service" do you mean "flow"?

Comment: Service mean a mule application. I would like to get events such as application stopped/started/deployed/undeployed.

Comment: You can listen to such Mule application events by listening to MuleContext notifictions. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/3.4.0/apidocs/index.html?org/mule/context/notification/MuleContextNotification.html